# php - somar a quantidade + preço em tabelas separadas

Tags: php

Boas.

Eu tenho a tabela Produtos + a tabela Cart

Quando eu faço Adicionar ao Cart.. a função adiciona 1 record na tabela Cart dizendo o Nome do User, ID do Produto e a Quantidade de produtos pedidos.

Agora eu quero somar a quantidade desse produtos + o preço.

```
function total_price($con) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['u_email'])) {

        $clientID = $_SESSION['u_id'];

        $total = 0;

        $getPriceTotal = "SELECT quantity, product_id FROM public_cart WHERE user_id='$clientID'";
        $run_total = mysqli_query($con, $getPriceTotal);   
        $savedItems = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_total);

        $quantity = $savedItems['quantity'];
        $productID = $savedItems['product_id'];


        $productQuery = "SELECT product_price FROM public_products WHERE product_id='$productID'";
        $run_product = mysqli_query($con, $productQuery);
        $product_search_price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_product);

        while($product_search_price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_product)) {

            $product_price = $product_search_price['product_price'];

            $sum = $product_price * $quantity;
            $total += $sum;

        }

         echo number_format($total, 2, '.', '');

    } else {

        echo "0";
    }
```

}

Mas pelo que vejo... não estou nem conseguindo, pois aparece valores diferentes ou super maiores...

O codigo simplesmente só esta contando de um produto. Mesmo fazendo um while.

Answer (score 1):

Aparentemente o seu `while` está posicionado incorretamente, considerando que você possui **n** registros na tabela **public_cart** mas cada registro possui apenas **um** produto.

Desta forma faz mais sentido:

```
function total_price($con) {

    if(isset($_SESSION['u_email'])) {

        $clientID = $_SESSION['u_id'];

        $total = 0;

        $getPriceTotal = "SELECT quantity, product_id FROM public_cart WHERE user_id='$clientID'";
        $run_total = mysqli_query($con, $getPriceTotal);   

        while ($savedItems = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_total)) {

            $quantity = $savedItems['quantity'];
            $productID = $savedItems['product_id'];

            $productQuery = "SELECT product_price FROM public_products WHERE product_id='$productID'";
            $run_product = mysqli_query($con, $productQuery);
            $product_search_price = mysqli_fetch_assoc($run_product);

            $product_price = $product_search_price['product_price'];

            $sum = $product_price * $quantity;
            $total += $sum;

        }

        echo number_format($total, 2, '.', '');

    } else {

        echo "0";

    }
}
```